# Error Installing caret on AWS Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, r, amazon-web-services, rcpp, r-caret

I'm trying to install the R package caret

```
R -e "install.packages('caret', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

on an Amazon Linux AMI but the dependancies RcppEigen,lme4, BradleyTerry2 fail.

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("caret", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") : installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("caret", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") : installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("caret", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") : installation of package ‘BradleyTerry2’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("caret", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") : installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I try to install RcppEigen I get (among other verbose massages):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRlapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRblas
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RcppEigen.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RcppEigen’
```

My environment

```
Amazon Linux version 2015.03
Linux version 3.4.37-40.44.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31005) (gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Mar 21 01:17:08 UTC 2013
```

It *seems* if it has to do with Red Hat vs. Ubuntu, but I can't find any answers here or elsewhere.

Comment: You need the Fortran compiler development package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository.

To do this: 
Modify `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`. Under the section marked `[epel]`, change `enabled=0` to `enabled=1`.

To temporarily enable the EPEL 6 repository, use the yum command line option `--enablerepo=epel`.

For more info see the [official documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#epel)

Comment: I ran `yum update --enablerepo=epel` and it did a bunch of things. I then tried to install RcppEigen and now have two additional "cannot find" lines `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath`

Comment: There is a dedicated mailing list `r-sig-fedora` for the RH family of distributions. You may have better luck over there...